# In Flutter, how do you pop to root, then immediately push with another screen?

Tags: flutter

For example, I have this navigation stack:

```
- <Some kind of top level screen>
- Create avatar
- Step 1
- Step 2
- Step 3
- ... Step n ...
- Verify result
```

On verify result, if it's success, I want to change the stack into this:

```
- <Some kind of top level screen>
- Success
```

So that if the user taps on the Android physical back button, it will immediately return to `<Some kind of top level screen>`, instead of `Verify result` screen, and doesn't matter how deep the navigation stack is.

How can I do this? The way I usually do is:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Success()),
    (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```

But this causes the Navigation stack to be:

```
- Success
```

If the user tap on Android physical back button, the app will be closed instead of returning to `<Some kind of top level screen>`. What I want is to pop all the stack until just before the `<Some kind of top level screen>` (which it can be various kind of screen that I cannot predict), and then push the Success screen on top of it.

There's actually a button in the `Success` screen that bring user to `<Some kind of top level screen>`, but I just learned that some user actually choose to tap on the Android physical back button instead of the big blue button I presented on the screen. To block back button on this screen feels like a wrong design / bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always returning `false` in the [predicate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html), do something like

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Success()),
    (Route<dynamic> route) => route != <Some kind of top level screen>,
);
```

Then the popping of route will spare you top level screen.

If you are using named route, the predicate could be

```
ModalRoute.withName('<Some kind of top level screen>')
```

More detail can be found RTFM

Comment: Is it possible to return something like `(Route<dynamic> route) => Navigator.stackCount == 1`? So no matter what top level screen is, it will be spared from being removed from the stack?

Comment: @ChenLiYong I don't think that information is available outside the Nagivator class, but pls check the docs.